# Найти повторения по полю date в коллекции и объединить повторяющиеся объекты в один

Tags: javascript

Есть коллекция вида

```
dict = [
  {
    date: '19.10.2018,
    hours: 2,
  },
  {
    date: '19.10.2018,
    hours: 10,
  },
  {
    date: '24.11.2010,
    hours: 4,
  },
]
```

Я бы хотел совместить поле hours у объектов с повторяющейся датой, то есть:

```
 [
      {
        date: '19.10.2018,
        hours: 12,
      },
      {
        date: '24.11.2010,
        hours: 4,
      },
    ]
```

Есть ли какие нибудь идеи как лучше это реализовать?
Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dict = [
  {
    date: '19.10.2018',
    hours: 2,
  },
  {
    date: '19.10.2018',
    hours: 10,
  },
  {
    date: '24.11.2010',
    hours: 4,
  },
],
obj = {};

dict.forEach(function(item){
 
  if(!obj[item.date]){
    obj[item.date] = item;
  } else {
    obj[item.date].hours =  obj[item.date].hours + item.hours;
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```